# Entire site times out after page is approved. Looks like it's caused by the NavNodes table in content database

Tags: 2010, navigation, publishing, content-and-structure, time-out

We've got a SharePoint site that recently started giving errors randomly when approving pages.

The only changes we made was to update the site to CU August 2012, and turn on UPS, but I'm not sure if this is the cause since the changes was made at least two weeks prior.

Using the ULS logs, and SQL Profiler it looks like the error is caused by multiple duplicate entries being added to the NavNodes table in the content database. It also balloons the SQL transaction log size dramatically.

The result is that all pages in the site times out. The only way to get it back up is to unpublish the page.

Unfortunately the logs isn't detailed enough to indicate what process is actually adding the entries to the NavNodes table, and I don't want to mess with the Content database.

The ULS has a lot of these errors though:

**An unexpected error occured while manipulating the navigational structure of this Web**

Has anybody experienced similar issues before?

Answer (score 0):

Known Issue with CU August 2012 - **http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/nb-NO/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/37ca573f-5731-417e-9cb6-8ef9202b3f79 **